# Citrix Receiver: An unspecified SSL error orrurred

Tags: ssl, tls, citrix, citrix-receiver

I just installed Citrix Receiver on a new machine. When I try to connect to our client’s Citrix farm (presumably a Citrix Access Gateway setup), I get the following error message as soon as I try to launch an application:

> An unspecified SSL error orrurred: 1407741A:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert decode error

Citrix Receiver version is 4.8 on Windows 7. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit, I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/588274/299725) indicating a similar message due to an apparent incompatibility in OpenSSL, which was temporarily resolved by downgrading. Apparently Citrix Receiver uses OpenSSL and has caught the same bug.

I removed Citrix Receiver 4.8, installed 4.5 (as this is a version some of my co-workers have used successfully), and I could connect without any problems.

Versions between 4.5 and 4.8 may also work, use at your own risk.

The change that introduced this behavior apparently was itself intended as a fix to work around nonstandard server behavior, thus upgrading the server (the Citrix Access Gateway in this case) to a newer, compatible version might also help if it is within your sphere of influence.